# Драйвер QMYSQL не может скомпилироватся

Tags: mysql, qt, драйвер

Вычитала кучу информации - все равно не работает. Как бы я не пробовала и не старалась, все равно пишет что не устанавливает этот драйвер. У меня Qt 5.14.2
Путь к файлу - D:\Qt\5.14.2\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers>
Команда - qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/include" MYSQL_LIBDIR="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/lib"
Нашла статью о том, что нужно удалять папку config.tests, и файлы config.cache, config.log, config.opt, config.summary. Все равно не работает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: Как и чем вы его компилируете?

Comment: Может поможет вот это https://stackoverflow.com/q/6483523/4711135

Answer (score 1):

Нашла решение данной проблемы.

Во-первых, убедитесь, что ваша рaзрядность MySQL совпадает с вашим компилятором.

Во-вторых, чтобы решить проблему, что не компилируется драйвер mysql, мне помогла [эта статья](http://pavelk.ru/mysql-5-5-i-qt-qtcreator-4-8-1-windows-7-x64). Большое спасибо автору!